# Finding the general term of this sum of combinations

Tags: combinatorics

$$A_{r,s}=1+r+{r+1\choose2}+\cdots+{r+s-1\choose s}$$

How to find the general expression of $A_{r,s}$.

Somehow, I feel it is related to the coefficients of expansion of $(1+x)^r$, but I am not sure how they could be related.

Comment: This is a sum along a main diagonal of Pascal's Triangle. Neat trick: the sum along a diagonal going left to right is immediately below and left of the last summand. Hence, $A_{r,s}=$ ${r+s}\choose s$.

Comment: This is called the Hockey Stick Identity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $A_{r,s}=\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{s} \binom{r+k-1}{k}$. Using Pascal's identity you can write the sum as $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{s} \left(\binom{r+k}{k}-\binom{r+k-1}{k-1}\right)$ then apply a change of variables on the second summand $u=k-1$ and cancel out terms.